# Designing a WCF Service properly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to create a WCF service at work that will handle request from different clients on the same machine and optionally from clients from a different machine but on the company's network (from the programmer computer - for debugging purposes). 
I need some suggestions on how to create the service because I am quite a beginner when it comes to WCF.

The service will get requests from the clients to perform different operations on the h/w devices located on the host machine.
The service need to contain several modules to support all kinds of h/w devices.
The programmers writing the client code will use those Modules objects to perform the operations.
Each Module needs to support Events towards the clients and exception throwing.

I wanted to know several things:

1. Is it possible to somehow export methods documentation to the
   clients? because it would be best, when the client code is being
   written, the programmer will be able to see what the method exactly
   does, what exceptions are being thrown and so on. I saw there is a
   way to share the API dll to the clients (keep in mind that most of
   the clients will run (and coded) on the same machine using .NET.
2. Is it possible to just throw exceptions in the service
   implementation methods? I will want to use most of .NET abilities
   and exceptions are one of them :)
3. The service will handle requests from different threads in every 
   client, is it possible to use the threads information (like thread 
   Id) or any other way in order to perform locking mechanism? for
   example, if two  threads of the same client are using the same h/w
   device channel the  second one will be blocked until the first one
   is finished.
4. Finally, I wanted to know what will be the best endpoints and
   configuration for this service?

I know it is a LOT, but i read the basics and i can't quite decide what is the proper way to achieve these requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend looking into using IErrorHandler for global exception handling on the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Yes. Just as you said, you can share the API dll, plus you can use a **Mex** endpoint to provide documentation on your service: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3def9d4f-ae3e-468b-90e6-3a069bac6376/when-to-use-wcf-mex-endpoint

2 - Yes. WCF throws and sends `FaultException` to the client whenever something goes bad and is not caught inside its own app.

3 - Clients run in their own threads or in a thread pool (I don`t remember exactly, but that shouldn't matter anyway). You can still use multi-threading features for clients with no problems. WCF is itself thread-safe, client wise. It basically abstracts everything in order to make it looks like it runs an entire dedicated application for each user.

4 - Is this application going to be a **web** or a **desktop**? In case you are going with **web**, I recommend using `nethttpbinding` for reliability. In case you are going with **desktop**, you could have better performance results with `nettcpbinding`.

Comment: One important note for point 2. If you allow any kind of exception that is **not** a `FaultException` or a `FaultException<T>` where `T` was specified in a `FaultContractAttribute` on the interface to bubble up to the client the clients connection to the server will be automatically closed and set to the to the `faulted` state. Allowing a `FaultException` to be raised does not close the connection.

Comment: On third point that is quite true by default, but changing the InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode of the servicebehaviour can cause some problems. But its all dependant on what kind of WCF service is being built.

Comment: 4 - is opinion based and you gave no arguments to support your opinion.

Comment: Point 4 - I would not use rest endpoint for this - the OP is looking for RPC style operations, so netTcpBinding would definitely provide the most perfomant approach as it's just raw socket communication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clarifications. So what InstanceContextMode and Concurrency Mode will be best suited for me?

Comment: @MaorB - Add a new question to ask this. Don't use comments. Thanks